# Blacklist or Whitelist applications on iphone using Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: iphone, ios, exchange-server, mdm, activesync

In Exchange ActiveSync, you can specify which applications you would like to allow and block. I found no document that specifies exactly how to do this.

I would like to block applications on iphone devices. Say for instance, I want to block facebook that has a package `"com.facebook.app" with id = 284882215`.

[app is here](https://itunes.apple.com/mt/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8). Please specify exactly how I should do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post a link to Exchange AS documentation. I saw it long-long time ago and I believe at the moment, it didn't have Blacklist and Whitelist.

More importantly, Exchange ActiveSync implementations on each platforms are limited. I haven't heard that Blacklisting was implemeneted on iOS platform.

Please take my answer with grain of salt, because it's based on quite old information.

BTW. Super primitive whitelisting can be accomplished by MDM. If device is supervised, you can install AppLock payload which will lock that device into one app.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/D/5DD33FDF-91F5-496D-9884-0A0B0EE698BB/%5BMS-ASPROV%5D.pdf. This is the most updated documentation there is.

Comment: Regarding AppLock, that can only be done on a single app. Thanks for your information. Upon further research it seems, this is not supported on iOS Devices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Exchange_ActiveSync_clients. However this comparison is outdated, but I have not been able to find a more recent comparison.

Comment: I will speculate a little bit. However, I believe Apple didn't want to implement ActiveSync device management part on purpose, because they implemented their own device management protocol (MDM). So, I don't think they improved a lot ActievSync support from since.